# header positioning , styling and browser window scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css, styling

i have problems with styling my header according to my requirements. my header contains 3 divs. first one contains table which in my case represents the tabs each tab is in "td tag" under common "tr tag" and  i used jquery "jquery-1.5.1.min.js" , i can't attach the js file i hope you can get it from the internet ,for the movement. the remaining two div are for button to move the table left and right.first, i hope you are understanding my case well.
my requirement that i couldn't meet them are:

1.i don't want the scrolling left-right  bar to  appears, i tried to set overflow attribute of the body :hidden then it worked , but when resizing the browser window there is now resize.

2.i don't want the remaining tabs which you can see them if you scroll right to appear.only i want the 7 tabs and when i click left or right the remaining tabs come.

3.i want when i brows this page from any computer to have the same size. I mean the header exactly fills the top of the browser window with no scrolling left or right and with exact height equals 65px.because it appears ok in my laptop ,but when i tried it in my friend laptop the header completely changes its position.

i think the position style effects the header i used the absolute ,but one of programmer i asked side it is not a good idea to set it as absolute !

this work took me more than a week i spent hours in restyling and repositioning ,but i don't get it. i hope you understand me and sorry for the long paragraph :/

my html code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <script src=jquery-1.5.1.min.js></script>

    <style type="text/css">

a.taps_link
{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:White;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 7px #111;
    color: #f5f5f5;
}
img.direction:hover
{
    padding:1px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;

} 
td.taps:hover
{
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left bottom,
    left top,
    color-stop(0.41, rgb(73,75,75)),
    color-stop(0.92, rgb(40,41,41))
);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(
    center bottom,
    rgb(73,75,75) 41%,
    rgb(40,41,41) 92%
);



    border-bottom-color:#494b4b;
}
td.taps
{
    text-align:center;
    text-align:center;
    min-width:140px;
    padding:6px 4px 6px 4px




}
body
{
    font-family:Tahoma;
    font-size:15px;

}

#header_top
{   
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 7px #111;
    color: #f5f5f5;
}

</style>
</head>
<body  style="  background-color:Green;">
<!--#D0D0D0-->
    <div style=" height:65px; background-color: Black; margin:-8px -8px 0px -8px ;">
<!--#336699#494B4B-->

   <div  id="tab_Menu_container" style=" overflow:inherit;margin-left:274px;position:absolute; z-index:3; margin-top:-10px; width:80%;"  >
          <table rules="all" id="tab_Menu" style=" margin-top:43px; position:absolute">
                <tr >
                    <td class="taps"><a class="taps_link" href="#">first</a></td>
                    <td class="taps"><a class="taps_link" href="#">aabbccddeeffgghhiijj</a></td>
                    <td class="taps"><a class="taps_link" href="#">aabbccddeeffgghhiijj</a></td>
                    <td class="taps"><a class="taps_link" href="#">aabbccddeeffgghhiijj</a></td>
                    <td class="taps"><a class="taps_link" href="#">aabbccddeeffgghhiijj</a></td>
                    <td class="taps"><a class="taps_link" href="#">aabbccddeeffgghhiijj</a></td>
                    <td class="taps"><a class="taps_link" href="#">aabbccddeeffgghhiijj</a></td>
                    <td class="taps"><a class="taps_link" href="#">aabbccddeeffgghhiijj</a></td>
                    <td class="taps"><a class="taps_link" href="#">aabbccddeeffgghhiijj</a></td>
                    <td class="taps"><a class="taps_link" href="#">aabbccddeeffgghhiijj</a></td>
                    <td class="taps"><a class="taps_link" href="#">aabbccddeeffgghhiijj</a></td>
                    <td class="taps"><a class="taps_link" href="#">aabbccddeeffgghhiijj</a></td>
                    <td class="taps"><a class="taps_link" href="#">aabbccddeeffgghhiijj</a></td>
                    <td class="taps"><a class="taps_link" href="#">aabbccddeeffgghhiijj</a></td>
                    <td class="taps"><a class="taps_link" href="#">aabbccddeeffgghhiijj</a></td>
                    <td class="taps"><a class="taps_link" href="#">aabbccddeeffgghhiijj</a></td>
                    <td class="taps"><a class="taps_link" href="#">aabbccddeeffgghhiijj</a></td>
                    <td class="taps"><a class="taps_link" href="#">aabbccddeeffgghhiijj</a></td>
                    <td class="taps"><a class="taps_link" href="#">aabbccddeeffgghhiijj</a></td>
                    <td class="taps"><a class="taps_link" href="#">aabbccddeeffgghhiijj</a></td>
                    <td class="taps"><a class="taps_link" href="#">aabbccddeeffgghhiijj</a></td>
                    <td class="taps"><a class="taps_link" href="#">aabbccddeeffgghhiijj</a></td>
                    <td class="taps"><a class="taps_link" href="#">aabbccddeeffgghhiijj</a></td>
                    <td class="taps"><a class="taps_link" href="#">aabbccddeeffgghhiijj</a></td>
                    <td class="taps"><a class="taps_link" href="#">aabbccddeeffgghhiijj</a></td>
                    <td class="taps"><a class="taps_link" href="#">aabbccddeeffgghhiijj</a></td>
                    <td class="taps"><a class="taps_link" href="#">final</a></td>


                </tr>
           </table>
    </div>
    <div id="upLeft_corner" style=" height:65px; width:274px;background-color:Aqua; position:absolute;z-index:4"> 
        <input type="button" value="<<" id="b" alt="previous situation" style="position:absolute;margin-left:240px;margin-top:41px" />
        <!--<img src="previous.png" id="b" alt="previous situation" style="position:absolute;margin-left:252px;margin-top:41px"/><<--> 
    </div>
    <div id="upRight_corner" style=" margin-left: 1318px;height:65px; width:112px; background-color: Aqua; position:absolute; z-index:4">
    <input type="button" value=">>" id="a" alt="next situation" style="position:absolute;margin-top:41px" />
    <!--
    <img src="next.png"  id="a" alt="next situation" style="position:absolute;margin-top:41px"/> 
    <img src="all.png"  id="all" alt="Show all situation" style="position:absolute;margin-top:41px;margin-left:29px; "/>-->

    </div>
</div>








<script>

    var counter,td_counter;
    counter=0;
    td_counter= document.getElementById('tab_Menu').getElementsByTagName('tr')[0].getElementsByTagName('td').length;
    console.log(td_counter);
if (td_counter <= 7) {

    $("#a").hide();

    $("#b").hide();

    $("#all").hide();
}

if (counter == 0) {
    $("#a").hide();//a= >>
}

//rigth
$("#a").click(function () {

        $("#b").show();
        counter--;
        $("#tab_Menu").animate({ "left": "+=150px" }, "slow");

    if(counter==0)
    {
        $("#a").hide();
    }


    /*$("#b").show();
    right_counter++;
    $("#tab_Menu").animate({ "left": "+=152px" }, "slow");
   var temp1 = td_counter - right_counter;
    if (temp1==temp) {
        $("#a").hide();

    }*/

});

//left
$("#b").click(function () {
        console.log(counter);
        $("#a").show();
        counter++;
        $("#tab_Menu").animate({ "left": "-=149px" }, "slow");

    if (counter+7>=td_counter)
    {
        $("#b").hide();
    }

    /*
    $("#a").show();
    left_counter++;
    $("#tab_Menu").animate({ "left": "-=152px" }, "slow");
    temp = td_counter - left_counter;
    if (temp == 7) {
        $("#b").hide();
        //left_counter = 0;
    }*/

});

</script>








</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if any body have ideas please help i still having problems.i used Gary Green way ,but doesn't work with table i am sure i did couple of errors ; because when i put the table or list it hides all the content not only the overflow :(

Comment: i still waiting for you programmers.

Answer (score 0):

Well to answer 1. you need to set the whole "moving panel" inside a div and set a `overflow: hidden;` on that div to get rid of the scrollbars.

Should you want to lighten your workload, you might want to take a look at these. This kind of thing for jquery has been done over and over again, why code it again?

http://webdesignledger.com/tutorials/13-super-useful-jquery-content-slider-scripts-and-tutorials

**Edit**: Take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/et7mc/3/ I've coded something that should help get you going. Like I said above though, it's really not needed. There are so many plugins out there to do just this.

Comment: thank you Gary Green . i tried what you said in" 1. you need to set the whole "moving panel" inside a div and set a overflow: hidden; on that div to get rid of the scrollbars.",but the whole table be hidden i don't know why .

Comment: could you help me with a small table having the same structure of my table ,i mean one tr with multiple td inside,using slider jquery to get the same result.

Comment: Gary Green, thank as big as i can't imagine. i will try it now:). is there any  documentation for all functions and options with demos.

Comment: but Gary, i can't replace 'a'  with table because when i put it inside the div of id hide overflow it hides all the table no matter the how td in the correct position . any idea . :(